# Oracle SQL query with Pivot and aggregate function

Tags: sql, oracle, aggregate, pivot-table

I am having trouble with pivot tables in oracle. I have a working example that gets counts of certain inventory items. There are two types of counts but I am only accounting for one type. I need to change my example to incorporate two types of counts and keeps the data "in-line" with each other (if that makes sense). I'll try my best to explain. Consider the following query:

```
select * 
from ( select state_code, city_code, equipment_type, sum(AVAILABLE_COUNT) as available_count
     from EQUIP_VIEW_TABLE
     group by state_code, city_code, equipment_type
     )
pivot (max(available_count)
     for (equipment_type) in 
     ('Sandbag' "CNT_SANDBAG",
      'Gabion Basket' "CNT_GABION_BASKET",
      'Rapid Deployment Floodwall' "CNT_RAPID_DEPLOYMENT_FLOODWALL",
      'Portable Coffer Dam' "CNT_PORTABLE_COFFER_DAM",
      'Polyethylene Sheeting' "CNT_POLYETHYLENE_SHEETING",
      'Pump' "CNT_PUMP"))
```

Now this query works well for one type of count ("available count"). The data is all on the same row corresponding to the state/city and no data is duplicated, i.e.

```
STATE  CITY      SANDBAGS BASKETS  FLOODWALL   DAM   SHEET   PUMP   
Texas  Austin    12        45      11           16   89      8
```

I need to account for a different type of count. I need to account for the "available count length" on certain pieces of equipment. I tried to accomplish this with the following query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM ( SELECT unique state_code, city_code, 
     equipment_type AS equipment_type_cnt, equipment_type as equipment_type_len, 
     sum(AVAILABLE_COUNT) AS available_count, SUM(AVAILABLE_COUNT_LENGTH) AS available_count_length
     FROM EQUIP_VIEW_TABLE
     GROUP BY state_code, city_code, equipment_type         )
pivot (MAX(available_count)
     FOR (equipment_type_cnt) IN 
     ('Sandbag' "CNT_SANDBAG",
      'Polyethylene Sheeting' "CNT_POLYETHYLENE_SHEETING",
      'Pump' "CNT_PUMP"))

pivot (MAX(available_count_length)
     FOR (equipment_type_len) IN 
     ('Gabion Basket' "CNT_GABION_BASKET",
      'Rapid Deployment Floodwall' "CNT_RAPID_DEPLOYMENT_FLOODWALL",
      'Portable Coffer Dam' "CNT_PORTABLE_COFFER_DAM"))
```

I tried to add another pivot section basically, and I thought it was working, but it duplicates values and puts them on different rows. Result set looks like

```
STATE  CITY      SANDBAGS SHEET  PUMP   BASKET   FLOODWALL   DAM   
Texas  Austin    12        89      8       16      -          -
Texas  Austin    12        89      8       -      11          -
Texas  Austin    12        89      8       -       -          16
```

It's duplicating rows in my result set. I would need all these values on the same line. I've been trying different ideas, but I still get duplicate values. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance for your help. I will post more info if my problem is a tad bit too complex or if I didn't explain well enough. Thanks.

Comment: please set up a sql fiddle for this.

Comment: ok i'll see what I can do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand what you're trying to do, I'd move the decision on which column to use up into the main query, with a `case` expression inside a single `sum()`:

```
SELECT unique state_code, city_code, 
  equipment_type, 
  sum(case when equipment_type in ('Gabion Basket',
      'Rapid Deployment Floodwall', 'Portable Coffer Dam')
    then AVAILABLE_COUNT_LENGTH
    else AVAILABLE_COUNT end) AS chosen_count
FROM EQUIP_VIEW_TABLE
GROUP BY state_code, city_code, equipment_type
```

and leave the pivot as it was:

```
SELECT * 
FROM ( SELECT unique state_code, city_code, 
     equipment_type, 
     sum(case when equipment_type in ('Gabion Basket',
         'Rapid Deployment Floodwall', 'Portable Coffer Dam')
       then AVAILABLE_COUNT_LENGTH
       else AVAILABLE_COUNT end) AS chosen_count
     FROM EQUIP_VIEW_TABLE
     GROUP BY state_code, city_code, equipment_type )
pivot (max(chosen_count)
     for (equipment_type) in 
     ('Sandbag' "CNT_SANDBAG",
      'Gabion Basket' "CNT_GABION_BASKET",
      'Rapid Deployment Floodwall' "CNT_RAPID_DEPLOYMENT_FLOODWALL",
      'Portable Coffer Dam' "CNT_PORTABLE_COFFER_DAM",
      'Polyethylene Sheeting' "CNT_POLYETHYLENE_SHEETING",
      'Pump' "CNT_PUMP"))
```

Comment: Bing0!....this was what I was trying to accomplish. I didn't think or really even begin to understand where to put the case statement at. On another one of my faield attmepts, I had the case case statement in the wrong spot. But this is what works. I've tested it and used it for my own purposes. Thanks a lot.